# How to block certain Ip ranges via ip2long in php

Tags: php

Lets assume I have the following **IP** ranges that I want to block
**89.96.53.158 and 89.96.53.189**

This how am trying to implement it.

**My questions:** is it the best way to do it as per code below. Is the coding below right for it

```
$ip = sprintf('%u', ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));
$start_ip = sprintf('%u', ip2long("89.96.53.158"));
$end_ip =   sprintf('%u', ip2long("89.96.53.189"));

// stop only ip range between 89.96.53.158 - 89.96.53.189


if ($ip >= $start_ip && $ip <=  $end_ip) {
   echo "you cannot access our site";
   exit();
}
```

can I also achieve that using `strpos()` functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I figured out another way to do it with **strpos()** method

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], "89.96") === 0)
{
    echo "you cannot access our site";
   exit();
}
```

If you notice, the `===` operator makes sure that the 89.96 is at the beginning of the **IP address**.
This means that you can specify as much of the **IP** address as you want, and it will block no matter what numbers come after it.

Comment: This code will block much more IP addresses than just those between 89.96.53.158 and 89.96.53.189. It will block 65536 addresses instead of 32. Or, in other words, how would you target only those 32 addresses?